# odoo 14 connection to database failed

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo, odoo-14

I do a clean Odoo 14 install and postgreSQL for a new Job, and I had this problem:
This is the odoo log file:

```
2022-09-26 22:08:19,881 4564 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
2022-09-26 22:08:19,883 4564 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2022 22:08:19] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0 0.000 0.019
2022-09-26 22:08:19,885 4564 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\odoo\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 306, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "D:\odoo\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 294, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 441, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 113, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 88, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 1328, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 1294, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "D:\odoo\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\middleware\shared_data.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 1479, in dispatch
    self.setup_db(httprequest)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 1385, in setup_db
    httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 1567, in db_monodb
    dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 1534, in db_list
    dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 384, in list_dbs
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 678, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 561, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 629, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "D:\odoo\python\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError - - -
```

I'm new in the world of database and coding... It seems a little problem but I do know how to resolve it. thanks for reading

Comment: It looks like your error message got cut off just where it was about to get informative.  Is there really nothing after that `- - -`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of the *postgresql* service. It seems it has not started.

Check status:

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

Restart:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```